# Java Selenium + 2Captcha + Submit Form

Tags: java, selenium, 2captcha

Hello i am trying to automate some process [here](https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/signin/?client_id=fe1fdbfa-f1a1-47ac-b793-e648fba25e86&redirect_uri=https://secure.eu.playstation.com/psnauth/PSNOAUTHResponse/pdc/&service_entity=urn:service-entity:psn&response_type=code&scope=psn:s2s&ui=pr&service_logo=ps&request_locale=en_GB&error=login_required&error_code=4165&error_description=User%20is%20not%20authenticated&no_captcha=false#/signin?entry=%2Fsignin)  . i am using 2captch to solve captcha , please [check out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiRAU.jpg) .

I have got site_key and api_key , now i am sending api_key + site_key and it is returning me response_token, i have added returned response token into `g-recaptcha-response` but it is not submitting form.

what i want is that :  i can solve captcha and submit form .

Here is my current java code :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver;
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/signin/?client_id=fe1fdbfa-f1a1-47ac-b793-e648fba25e86&redirect_uri=https://secure.eu.playstation.com/psnauth/PSNOAUTHResponse/pdc/&service_entity=urn:service-entity:psn&response_type=code&scope=psn:s2s&ui=pr&service_logo=ps&request_locale=en_GB&error=login_required&error_code=4165&error_description=User+is+not+authenticated&no_captcha=false#/signin?entry=%2Fsignin");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Sign-In ID (Email Address)']")).sendKeys("email");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Password']")).sendKeys("password");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='primary-button row-button text-button touch-feedback']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    By captcha = By.xpath("//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']");
    String src = driver.findElement(captcha).getAttribute("src");
    String key = getKey(src);
    System.out.println(key);

    String apiKey = "API_KEY";
    String googleKey = key;
    String pageUrl = "https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/signin/?client_id=fe1fdbfa-f1a1-47ac-b793-e648fba25e86&redirect_uri=https://secure.eu.playstation.com/psnauth/PSNOAUTHResponse/pdc/&service_entity=urn:service-entity:psn&response_type=code&scope=psn:s2s&ui=pr&service_logo=ps&request_locale=en_GB&error=login_required&error_code=4165&error_description=User+is+not+authenticated&no_captcha=false#/signin?entry=%2Fsignin";
    String proxyIp = "183.38.231.131";
    String proxyPort = "8888";
    String proxyUser = "username";
    String proxyPw = "password";


    TwoCaptchaService service = new TwoCaptchaService(apiKey, googleKey, pageUrl, proxyIp, proxyPort, proxyUser, proxyPw, ProxyType.HTTP);

    try {
        String responseToken = service.solveCaptcha();
        System.out.println("The response token is: " + responseToken);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"g-recaptcha-response\").innerHTML = \'"+responseToken+"\';");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR case 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR case 2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

UPDATED CODE :

```
          js.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"g-recaptcha-response\").innerHTML = \'" + responseToken + "\';");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        WebElement frameElement = driver.findElement(captcha);
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);         
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('recaptcha-verify-button').click();");
```

it is clicking on button but , it shows `Please select all matching images.`
 . please check out [screenshot](https://ibb.co/Fq6P0nw)

Comment: You need to click something to submit the form. I can't tell what it is because the site wants me to log in.

Comment: if i click on "singn in button " it again open up captcha box and ask me to select images ...

Comment: @pguardiario you can try to login with this sample account . eamil = "vyhylyw@dropjar.com" pass = "131313aa" . i hope you can help me out

Comment: @Awais check my answer, everything you did is good, but you forgot to submit it

Comment: @Awais I couldn't make it but I will try something more tomorrow. If you did it, please warn me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is submit it like this:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='" + responseToken + "';");
Thread.sleep(500);
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('captcha-form').submit();");
```

also don't forget to check this ID : "captcha-form", it can be different

To reach to element "recaptcha-verify-button":

After you got the response from the API;

```
By frame = By.xpath("//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']");

WebElement frameElement = driver.findElement(frame);

driver.switchTo.frame(frameElement);
```

then you can execute your script. Finally, for your script if your captcha form is a button

you

> cannot call submit();

you

> can call click();

**Final Answer:**

Also check this: `js.executeScript("widgetVerified('TOKEN');");`

To find the function called `widgetVerified()` please run this code in the console.

```
___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]
```

this will return a json, inside of that json try to find the callback function in @Awais case it was `wigdetVerified(e)`

> Warn : Don't use any adblocker

Comment: i really appreciate your effort , i have tried this `'recaptcha-verify-button'` but it says :
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'submit' of null` . here is screenshot : https://ibb.co/KWQ0w8M

Comment: @Awais to be able to reach that element you firstly need to switch to the frame, I will edit my answer, please check it.

Comment: Aziz Besli , thank you , i have updated my question , can you please check  it out : it shows this `Please select all matching images.` when Script click on button .

Comment: @Awais there must be form to submit it. But I couldn't find it in the source code. I think in this version of captcha it is a bit different

Comment: i was checking about callback function , please check this screenshot : https://ibb.co/Mhj7syM , maybe you can get some clue , as you know better then me that how it is all working at all ...

Comment: @Awais can you check this after you got the response from the server: js.executeScript("widgetVerified('TOKEN');
");

Comment: no luck :( `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: widgetVerified is not defined`

Comment: @Awais you need to switch to default content: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); then run that script js.executeScript("widgetVerified('token');"); or just delete switchToFrame() function and try to run it

Comment: thank you very much , you have helped me twice ... Allah bless you brother